# LoadLibrary() returns 0 in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, dllimport, loadlibrary

I am creating an Autodesk Revit add-in in C#. Output of this project is a DLL itself. Within this project, I am loading another unmanaged DLL by calling:

`IntPtr pDll = LoadLibrary("E:\\Rep3DLib\\builds\\Release\\Index.dll");
int a = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();`

Within debugger, I see that `pDll` has value 0 and `a` has value 127 (Error: The specified procedure could not be found.). This is surprising because I am not even looking any particular procedure within the DLL. I just want to load the DLL.

Now I delete the unmanaged DLL from `E:\\Rep3DLib\\builds\\Release\\Index.dll` and in the above code, `a` has value 126 (Error: The specified module could not be found.). This does make sense. It also means that when the DLL is present at the correct location, the code is able to find it but somehow it's looking for a procedure which it's not able to find.

To debug this problem, I created another project within the same solution. Here's the code for this project:

```
namespace testIndex {
    class Program {

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            IntPtr pDll = LoadLibrary("E:\\Rep3DLib\\builds\\Release\\Index.dll");
            int a = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, `pDll` has a non-zero value and I am able to call the functions defined within the `Index.dll`.

Note that both the projects have target platform as x64. I also verified that if I build the Revit add-in and run it on a different machine, it does find the DLL. So somehow it's not finding the DLL only on my machine although the path `E:\\Rep3DLib\\builds\\Release\\Index.dll` is definitely correct.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: what about pinvoke?

Comment: I am new to C# and .Net. I am guessing that PInvoke uses DllImport, am I correct? In any case, before using LoadLibrary(), I was using DllImport directly. In other words, I had:

`        [DllImport("Index.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr createIndex(float spacing, IntPtr errorCode);`

After calling `createIndex()`, I was getting the error that `Index.dll` could not be found. This was even if I was calling `SetDllDirectory("E:\\Rep3DLib\\builds\\Release");` before calling `createIndex()`.

I switched to `LoadLibrary()` because I thought it would be easier to debug.

Comment: Could the dll on your machine be corrupt?

Comment: Sam, if that were the case, the code in second project shouldn't work as well, right? But code in the second project is working perfectly.

Comment: Could the path you hand to LoadLibrary be mistyped in the plugin project?  Or perhaps the path contains a misspelling in the filesystem (eg. a directory is misspelled) ?

Comment: Is the security environment on the machine with the problems the same as the machine where it works?  Specifically, does the account the application is running under have permission to read and execute the dll?

Comment: Sam, that's a good point but that doesn't seem to be the problem. I just verified again. I changed the path to @"E:\Rep3DLib\builds\Release\Index.dll" in both the projects. LoadLibrary() doesn't work in add-in project but works in the second project. I also pasted this path in the File Explorer and it does point to the DLL.

Comment: Bradley, the security might be different. The machine where it works is Windows Server and where it doesn't work is Windows 10 Pro. If anything, I would assume that Server will have stricter security than Windows 10 Pro.

Also the second project (mentioned in the original description), works on Windows 10 Pro. So it doesn't look like a security issue.

Comment: It could also be a dependency issue, where the dll you are loading has dependencies on another dll that it can't locate.  In this case, the error might be unclear about what it can't find.  You can use something like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) to track down any missing dependencies.

Comment: Bradley, that's a good point. I have done that already. Dependency walker shows that all the dependencies are found. Also, if it were a dependency problem, why would LoadLibrary() work in second project and not in add-in project?

Comment: Do any of the suggestions on [this page](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/meravk/2015/08/13/loadlibrary-returns-error-code-127/) help?

Comment: you can use ProcMon to troubleshoot a file not found error.

Comment: Sheng, I used ProcMon but all files are eventually found.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer to the question I posted above. My add-in was using a dependent DLL named "pcl_features_release.dll". Revit was loading another add-in before mine, which was also loading its own "pcl_features_release.dll" which might be slightly different than mine. As a result, although Revit was finding my DLL, it was not able to load it.

Another question: In this case, two add-ins are dependent on "pcl_features_release.dll", which is a DLL supplied by Point Cloud Library (http://pointclouds.org/). What is the best practice to avoid conflict in such cases. I can not change someone else's add-in. How do I make sure that my add-in loads my "pcl_features_release.dll" that is being supplied with the add-in?

Comment: Is giving your copy of the DLL a unique name an option?

Comment: I can give it a shot. The DLLs are being generated using a CMake project so I'll need to figure out how to append a version number or some unique string to the library file names.